# $|x-s|= d(x,S)$ for some $s\in S$ if $S$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let $ S\subset \Bbb{R} $, define for any $x\in \Bbb{R}$ the distance between x and the set $S$ by
$$ d(x,S) = \inf \{|x-s|: s\in S\}$$

Prove the following: 
If $S$ is compact then for every $x\in \Bbb{R} $ there is $s\in S$ such that $$|x-s|= d(x,S)$$
I am at a loss with this problem.

Comment: Try with the characterization of $\inf$. For all $n$ there is some $s_n \in S$ such that $d(x,s_n)$...

Comment: A compact set is a closed and bounded set is a union of closed intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m=d(x,S)=\inf\{|x-s|: s\in S\}$. By definition of inf we have $m\leq |x-s|$ for all $s\in S$ but (just one way to put it) we may get arbitrarily close to the inf, so for any $n\geq 1$ there is $s_n\in S$ for which 
  $$ m \leq |x-s_n| < m+1/n$$
Now Hints:
(1) Compactness of $S$ means here that $s_n$ has a convergent subsequence $(s_{n_k})_{k\geq 1}$ and (2) you may remark that the function $s\in S\mapsto |x-s|$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of your $d(\cdot, \cdot)$, if $L = d(x, S)$, then $S$ contains a sequence $\{s_{n}\}_{n \geq 0}$ such that the absolute values
$$
|x - s_{n}|
$$
form a decreasing sequence that converges to $L$.  It is not difficult to show that $\{s_{n}\}_{n \geq 0}$ is Cauchy.  Consequently, $\{s_{n}\}_{n \geq 0}$ converges, and the limit, which we will denote by $s$, is in $S$ because $S$ is compact (and, in metric spaces, compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Euclidean_space).

Answer (score 1):

To fill in a gap in @avs 's solution, and provide a slightly different proof.

Define a rel-valued function $g$ on $S$ by $$ g(y)=d(x,y),$$ for $y \in S$.

Use triangle inequality to show that this is continuous.
Since this is a nonnegative function, it has an infimum. But a continuous function on a compact set attains its infimum. Thus, it is a minimum, in fact.